# Primalscript/Primalforms not recognizing powershell cmdlets

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that runs and compiles within the powershell ISE. However, I need to compress it into an .exe so that the users that will use my application can open it easily. To do this I have found that I should use either primalcript or primalforms. The problem is that when I try to run the script, certain cmdlets output error messages on either of these two programs.

For example the line:

```
$freeRam = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | 
Select-Object -expand FreePhysicalMemory
```

Returns this in PrimalScript:

> ERROR: Get-CimInstance : The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not recognized
>   as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again At C:\Users\sieredzkian\Desktop\New 
>   folder\User_Launched_Application_3.ps1:166 char:31 + $freeRam =
>   Get-CimInstance <<<<  -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object
>   -expand FreePhysicalMemory + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Get-CimInstance:String) [], CommandNotFoundException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Whereas in powershell it runs...

Why can it not find the cmdlets? It also does this for a few other cmdlets like Out-GridView

EDIT:
My original problem was caused by using primalscript 2011 where only powershell V2 was supported. I was able to fix this by installing the trial version of primalscript 2016. This enabled me to have powershell V3 like I was using in the ISE.

Comment: Did you set a powershell version preference? Primalscript (2016) should compile code up to Powershell v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-CimInstance` Require PowerShell version 3 and later... make sure you set it in the PowerShell version menu

[image: Serach for this menu]

Another option (in case your PowerShell version is 2 or less) is to use `Get-WmiObject` instead of `Get-CimInstance` so it should looks like:

```
$freeRam = Get-WmiObject -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object -expand FreePhysicalMemory
```

Comment: I am unable to select v3 on the UI for some reason

Comment: so if not later then v3, change your script to Get-WmiObject, as explained.

Comment: I ended up being able to clear the cache and restarted the program. The v3 button became clickable. Thanks for your help!